# Scroll by line in terminal rather than by page Shift + PgUp

Tags: command-line, terminal, scrolling

Is there a keyboard way to scroll the terminal by line the same way we scroll with mouse wheel?

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> give only by-page scrolling. I would like to scroll slowly as with mouse wheel.

My search on Google was not fruitful.

**Update**

From your comments, I see that it is not a general manipulation to all terminals.  I'm asking about Fedora 22 terminal, opened by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or "System" → "Terminal".

Follow-up with @Stephane: Would that be "virtual console on Fedora" or "any of the many X11 terminal emulators" in this case? What is the difference?

Pardon me for the confusion; I am new to Linux and still learning.

Comment: For xterm, it's configurable.  Probably not generally available for other terminals.

Comment: Using what terminal? You can do this in tools like `screen` or `tmux` for example. I'm sure you can configure some terminals to do so as well. Please [edit] and tell us what you work with.

Comment: See also `^E`/`^Y` in vi/less/screen

Comment: Do you mean the virtual console on Fedora or any of the many X11 terminal emulators available for the several desktop environments available there?

Comment: On the console (what you reach with Ctrl+Alt+F2), no. In a GUI terminal, maybe: it depends which terminal — there are many. Which one you get depends on the desktop environment and its configuration, not on the distribution. You can tell by running `ps $PPID` in the terminal.

Comment: you can do it with a user-space console such as [`kmscon`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KMSCON). if you installed it and configured your `getty` process correctly, yes, it would work with *`SHIFT+UP`* after pressing *`CTRL+ALT+F2`*.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: try CTRL+SHIFT+Up/Down .

Longer answer:
As other mentioned, this question is not a simply as it seems, because there are different programs that 'wrap' what you see as the terminal, and each might have its own keyboard shortcuts.

CTRL+SHIFT+Up/Down will work in a GUI terminal called "gnome terminal", and if you're using the default Fedora 22 installation, and select "System Terminal" - you are likely using it.

If you are using a text mode virtual terminal (the one that appears when pressing CTRL+ALT+F2), then these keys will not likely work.

For more advance usage, you might want to re-think why you need to 'scroll up'.
If it is because a program you are using outputs a long text and you need to "look back", consider learning how to use `more` or `less` programs which are better at examining long output.
If it is because you want to see previous commands you've typed, consider using `history`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> for the majority of terminals.

If they don't work, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> should instead.

Answer (score -2):

In terminator works with Shift+control+alt